# Control of individual textbox in a continuous form

Tags: ms-access-2010

Is there any way to control each textbox in a continuous form?

I've made a continuous form and i'd like to show a visual indication, if the field contains a comment. (a similar function, when Excel has a triangle on a cell, that indicates a comment). I've added rectangles on top of the textboxes and i want to control the .visible of the rectangle on every textbox, based on a record in a field. Furthermore i'd like to control the controltiptext on each individual textbox on the continuous form. Is that possible?

Comment: You are looking for **Conditional formatting**, that's the only way to control things per row in a continuous form.

Comment: @Andre I already use that, as a coloring tool. That's sad though :-(